# What if I upgrade Ubuntu 16.04 with AMDGPU-PRO to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, amd-graphics, gpu, 18.04

I'm trying to make AMDGPU-PRO driver working in Ubuntu 18.04, but without success. So I'm wondering, what would happen if I upgrade a fully working Ubuntu 16.04 with AMDGPU-PRO installed to Ubuntu 18.04?

Will I lose the AMDGPU-PRO? Or maybe will it work?

Thanks in advance for answers.

Answer (score 2):

It will almost certainly not work. From my experience the AMDGPU-PRO drivers have very specific kernel dependencies that are only satisfied by 16.04. If you upgrade the 18.04 your kernel jumps way ahead of that expected by the AMDGPU-PRO driver.